# How to load local image (saved in gallery) using piccaso in android

Tags: android, picasso

I am using **`Picasso`** lib to download images from a `url` and then saving it into my gallery. Images are being saved very well. then i need to load the image from my local uri i.e. from my gallery. But , apparently, its not loading from my gallery. Here is my code to load from gallery.

My local uri is "**`/storage/emulated/0/ Messages/IMAGE_9.jpg`**"

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(new File(_localImageUrl))
                        .placeholder(R.id.downloadingImageProgress)
                        .error(R.drawable.chat_sendbtn_active)
                        .into(holder.buddyImageMessage, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see `can't open /storage/emulated/0/ Messages/IMAGE_9.jpg` in your `LogCat` add read from external storage permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

See [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will fix your problem.

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(new File(_localImageUrl)).fit().into(holder.buddyImageMessage);

But first add permision in manifest for reading from sd card

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this permission for reading google photos

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS"/>
```